# Email Intent issue. Cannot select an email option

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Updated:

Managed to sort the loading of gmail.

Now I cannot set the 'To', 'subject' and 'message' fields of gmail when the intent is loaded.

Screenshot to show my email layout:

[image]

Screenshot to show the gmail intent loaded. But without the fields being set from the passed details.

[image]

Code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View sendEmailClick) {


    Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sendEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAdd);  
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSub); 
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailMess); 
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Send email"));

       //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Send email..."));
}
```

Comment: Use intent.setType("text/plain");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default email client does not have an account, it should not register itself for `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Make sure that you have an account added to the app and try to send your email again. As noted, using `"text/plain"` as the type.

[From what I can find on short notice:](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email/+/5da9e7359fa4530c700d6db6eab565d5efd7be4c/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MessageCompose"
            android:label="@string/compose_title"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            >
```

The compose Activity is not enabled by default and should be enabled once you add an account.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have added my gmail account and now when i clikc the send button the onclick method starts the intent. My only issue now Is I cannot seem to set the Gmail 'To' 'subject' and 'message' fields with my passed intent details? I will update my questions to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can send also email without external application :

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String[] recipients = new String[]{"my@email.com", "",};

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");

emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean by this that I do notneed to select an email app to sen my email? I have tried your startActivity and I get the same issue. Im not using a string array is this need for this method to work? Im just setting my '.EXTRA_EMAIL' with my edittext value.

Comment: Yes you not need application to send application. You can declarate your edittext and get text `String s = et.getText().toString();` . Now you can `... EXTRA_TEXT, s);`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email"));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.i("app name", "Unable to send email");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the second part ti this sorted. You need to pass it to Gmail as a String array, not just as a pure string. Hopefully that will save other people problems in the future!